# start/continue parent process only after completing child process

Tags: perl

I want to do some parallel child process but, all the child process are done then only i want to start/continue my parent process. below is my sample code

```
    foreach ('abc.gz','efg.gz','123.gz','xyz.gz')
    {
        my $pid = fork;
        if ($pid == 0) {            
            exec("tar -xvf $_");
            exit 0;
        }
    }
    wait();
    `tar -xvf 'parent.gz'`;
```

in the above code i want to extract my "parent.gz" at the end of all the child process extraction. but, it is extracting the "parent.gz" in the middle of the child process. So, please help me.

I can use only perl core modules, my perl version is v5.10.1

Thanks 
Baski

Comment: Why are you limited to perl core modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is - `fork` is all about parallel processing, and your `wait()` call doesn't necessarily wait on all children. Indeed - it only waits for the first, and returns the pid. See: [`perldoc wait`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wait.html)

I will also point out though - you're probably not going to gain much by forking here. `fork` doesn't make anything go faster - it merely lifts some contention blocks, and lets you use certain resources (cpus) in parallel. Your limiting factor here is *probably* not the CPU (it might be, thanks to the decompression - if you weren't doing `.gz` files it almost certainly wouldn't be).  But disks are usually the slowest thing on your system, and that'll *likely* be your limiting factor. By parallel writing you won't therefore gain much speed at all.

Also: You probably want the `z` flag in your tar command, because they look like `gzip` compressed files (I'm assuming they're also tarballs, because this makes no sense at all if they're not).

By far the easiest way of doing this is the `Parallel::ForkManager` module:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Parallel::ForkManager;

my $manager = Parallel::ForkManager -> new ( 10 ); 
foreach ('abc.gz','efg.gz','123.gz','xyz.gz')
{
    $manager -> start and next;            
        exec("tar -xvf $_");
        exit 0;   #probably redundant, because exec will mean it's not called. 
    $manager -> finish;
}
$manager -> wait_all_children
`tar -xvf 'parent.gz'`;
```

However if you're set on not using extra modules (which really - is a limitation that comes up frequently, and is a bad limitation to apply). You could simply call `wait` 3 times, but I don't like that solution, because it can be tripped up by other implicit forks.

So I would suggest use `waitpid()` instead.

```
my @pids; 
foreach ('abc.gz','efg.gz','123.gz','xyz.gz')
{
    my $pid = fork;
    if ($pid == 0) {            
        exec("tar -xvf $_");
        exit 0;
    } 
    else { 
       push ( @pids, $pid ); 
    }
}
foreach my $pid ( @pids ) {
   print "Waiting for pid $pid\n"; 
   waitpid ( $pid, 0 ); 
}

`tar -xvf 'parent.gz'`;
```

Alternatively, as a way to reap all children:

```
my $result = wait(); 
while ( $result >= 0 ) {
    $result = wait(); 
}
```

`wait` should return `-1` if there's no children, which will break the loop.

Or as [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) points out this can be reduced to:

```
1 while wait > 0;
```

(Which does the same thing, more concisely)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable information. The reason for limitation is the script will be run in client machine so, we can't expect any third party modules.

Comment: Generally I'd suggest that's a false economy. I mean, CPAN is a well known and well supported resource for modules. Things like `Parallel::ForkManager` are really quite good for making better code overall - which hopefully you can see by the code illustrations.

Comment: @Sobrique, this is probably a daft question but I'll ask anyway. You created 10 threads/processes in your example. If there are 50 files to process, would Parallel::ForkManager queue the remaining 40 processes, similar to a threadpool?

Comment: Exactly that, yes. That "10" is a concurrency limit in `Parallel::ForkManager`. the OP indicated 3 files, so it's irrelevant to the example, but I'd generally call it good form to set a limit so you don't accidentally forkbomb :)

Comment: I was being lazy and just tried it. I tried a PF example a long time ago which was a lot more involved than yours. I tried yours and in 3 lines of code I have exactly what I need. Thank you.

Comment: `Parallel::ForkManager` is one of the examples I use for why 'using mods' is well worth doing. Because `fork` has a bunch of gotchas and slightly counter-intuitive things going on with it (like - `fork` in a loop, and each of the children also `fork` if you're not careful)

Comment: The exit is indeed redundant with finish.

Comment: Shorter: `1 while wait > 0;`

Comment: On Windows, process id's can be negative (or rather, "process" ids can be negative) and `wait` can return a negative value.